# Rewriting static files in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have application in subfolder `http://example.com/some/other/sub/folder/`.
And .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteBase /some/other/sub/folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Template files contain absolute URL to the images, js and css files: `/images/header.png`, `/js/common.js` etc.

My problem is that static files with absolute paths is not accessible.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that with a reference of an absolute URL path `/images/header.png` you actually reference `/images/header.png` and not `/some/other/sub/folder/images/header.png`.

Either use relative URL paths that work with `/some/other/sub/folder/` as the base path. Or use absolute URL paths like `/some/other/sub/folder/images/header.png` that then are independent to the actual base path.

Comment: thanks a lot, but most easy solution that we found is move application to root of server;)